# Dynamically adding tests to my Test Cases

Tags: python, python-unittest

I wish to add multiple tests to my Test Cases, instead of doing the following:

```
class TestRestart(unittest.TestCase):

   ...

   def test_modes(self):
      for mode in modes:
         machine.set_mode(mode)
         self.assertTrue(machine.restart())
```

in many of my tests, I wish to test each mode in its own function. I'm not in a position right now to use libraries like nose. I was thinking I could use the `add_tests` method below to help me do this:

```
import unittest

def build_name_1(a):
   return "test " + str(a[0]) + "_" + str(a[1])

def build_name_2(a):
   return "test " + str(a[0]) + "_" + str(a[1]) + "_" + str(a[2])

def add_tests(cls, args, name_builder):
   for a in args:
      def tb(a):
         return lambda self: self.test_body(*a)
      setattr(cls, name_builder(a), tb(a))

class TestEqual(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_body(self, i, j):
      self.assertNotEquals(0, i-j)

args = ((0,0),(1,1))
add_tests(TestEqual, args, build_name_1)

class TestBetween(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_body(self, i, j, k):
      self.assertTrue(i<j<k)

args = ((2,1,2),(2,2,3))
add_tests(TestBetween, args, build_name_2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Is it possible to move the `add_tests` call to within the TestEqual and TestBetween classes instead of having them outside the classes as I do above? Wouldn't this be better?

What improvements might I make to `add_tests`? How might I get it to handle named arguments?

Comment: You need to be more clear about your data manipulation. It seems like you want to test something in a function and then if it meets see criteria, perform more tests, or perhaps continue the function?

Comment: If this is the case you are going to need to setup an internal state in your function, this is easiest to do with classes. Otherwise you will have to run the first test and return the parameters to the second, then call the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your `add_tests` function a class decorator, so that it gets called right at class creation time, rather than separately. If you don't mind deeply nested functions, you can pass in various arguments too.

Here's a version that's equivalent to what you're doing now, just in decorator-factory form:

```
def add_tests(args, name_builder):
   def decorator(cls):
      for a in args:
          def tb(a):
              return lambda self: self.test_body(*a)
          setattr(cls, name_builder(a), tb(a))
      return cls
```

You'd call it with:

```
@add_tests(args, build_name1)
class TestEquals(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

You could probably also handle keyword arguments by taking a sequence of `kwargs` dicts in addition to the sequence of `args` tuples. Then you'd just pass them on to the test function, which could be passed as a callable, or if you're dealing with a method, by name (since the class decorator is called before the class is bound to its name). Try this (but note that the `name_builder` function gets passed an additional argument, so it will need to be updated so it can deal with kwargs too!):

```
def add_tests(args_sequence, kwargs_sequence, name_builder, test_func=None):
   def decorator(cls):
      if test_func is None:
          test_func = cls.test_body      # fall back on your current behavior
      elif isinstance(test_func, str):
          test_func = getattr(cls, test_func)
      for args, kwargs in zip(args_sequence, kwargs_sequence):
          def tb(a, kw):
              return lambda self: test_func(self, *a, **kw)
          setattr(cls, name_builder(args, kwargs), tb(args, kwargs))
      return cls
```

You could then do your final examples with:

```
@add_tests([(mode.SILENT,), (mode.NOISY,)], [{}, {}], build_name_mode, "test_mode_flow")
@add_tests([(1,), ()], [{"speed":33}, {"speed":22, "gear":4}], # can mix args and kwargs
           build_gear_mode, "test_gear_flow")
class TestRestart(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import unittest

def outer(i, j):
    """Saves i and j in the inner scope, will be passed an
    instance of Foo on call to inner.
    """
    def inner(inst):
        inst.assertNotEqual(i, j)

    return inner

class Meta(type):
    """Builds test functions before unittest does its discovery.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i, j in self.tests:
            setattr(self, self.namebuilder(i, j), outer(i, j))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)        

class Foo(unittest.TestCase, metaclass=Meta):
    def namebuilder(*args):
        return "test_{}_{}".format(*args)

    tests = [(i, j) for i in range(10) for j in range(i+1, 10)]

class Bar(unittest.TestCase, metaclass=Meta):
    def namebuilder(*args):
        return "test_labeled_differently_{}_{}".format(*args)

    tests= [(i, i) for i in range(10)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here's one way to do it using a meta class. `unittest` discovers test functions before your class will be instantiated. Think of a class as an instance-builder and a meta class as a class-builder. The meta class will create all of your test functions, so that when the default unittest loader in loader.py https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/322ee2f2e922/Lib/unittest/loader.py calls the function getTestCaseNames, it will find the dynamically created tests. I've included the function from loader.py so you can see for yourself how it works.

```
def getTestCaseNames(self, testCaseClass):
    """Return a sorted sequence of method names found within testCaseClass
    """
    def isTestMethod(attrname, testCaseClass=testCaseClass,
                     prefix=self.testMethodPrefix):
        return attrname.startswith(prefix) and \
            callable(getattr(testCaseClass, attrname))
    testFnNames = list(filter(isTestMethod, dir(testCaseClass)))
    if self.sortTestMethodsUsing:
        testFnNames.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(self.sortTestMethodsUsing))
    return testFnNames
```

Comment: Unless `unittest`'s discovery process is different than I think it is, I don't think this will change anything. The test methods were already being installed at method import time (because the calls to `add_tests` are at the top level), not at instantiation time.

Comment: @Blckknght The OP's question was how to accomplish the same thing they were doing but with add_tests happening within the classes. I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this way avoids repetition.